# Why am I getting an unexpected T_NEW error in PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created a user model in Code Igniter.

```
class User extends CI_Model {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function new($username, $email, $password, $studentID="") {
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO user VALUES (0, '$username', '$email', '$password', '$studentID')");
    }
}
```

However, I am getting this PHP error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_NEW, expecting T_STRING in /home/davidfaux/testApp/application/models/user.php on line 12
```

Line 12, by the way, is this line.

```
public function new($username, $email, $password, $studentID="") {
```

What is a T_NEW? Why am I getting the error?

Comment: `public function new` should be `public function newUser`. New is for creating instances of classes. And the keyword cannot be used as a function name. BTW Isn´t your code highlighting already telling you this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`new` is a reserved word for creating new objects, like `new Person('Joe')`.
You should rename your function.

See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php for reference.

> These words have special meaning in PHP. Some of them represent things
>   which look like functions, some look like constants, and so on--but
>   they're not, really: they are language constructs. You cannot use any
>   of the following words as constants, class names, function or method
>   names. Using them as variable names is generally OK, but could lead to
>   confusion.

Answer (score 2):

The `new` function is a reserved keyword for instantiating an object and isn't an overridable function.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct.

But my case was different and I was redirected here, for the same error search.

My case:
The project was working on server1.
For R&D i uploaded this same code on server2.
On server2 i faced the above error.

**Reason:

"Support for 'NEW' was added in PHP 7.0"**

So i checked my PHP version and it was lower.
Check you PHP version with phpinfo();