# How can I name my controller 'New' in codeigniter

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, variables, constants

I'm trying to name my controller 'New' in codeigniter but get the following error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_NEW, expecting T_STRING in
C:\site\application\controllers\new.php on line 3
```

(although New doesn't seem to be reserved according to CI user guide - > https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/reserved_names.html)

Any workaround would be appreciated. tx!

Comment: It's not a reserved name to CodeIgniter, but it *is* a [PHP keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php). You're not going to be able to call anything that.

Comment: isn't there any way around it?

Comment: Not unless you consider naming it something else to be a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

`new` is reserved keyword in php. You can't use that for class name.

See list of [reserved keywords](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php).

Possible duplicate questions [Why am I getting an unexpected T_NEW error in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575590/why-am-i-getting-an-unexpected-t-new-error-in-php)